# purescript anonymous function arguments on nested records?

Tags: purescript

Is it possible to apply anonymous function arguments to nested records somehow in the followign way?

```
type UName = {fname :: String, lname :: String}
type XName = { xname :: UName, addr :: String}

updateU = _ { xname : { fname : _ } } -- not ok
-- or 
updateU = _ { xname.fname = _ } -- not ok
-- or 
updateU = _ { xname : fname = _ } } -- not ok
```

Above trials say that context is invalid. Aim is to implement:

```
updateU = \x ->  { xname : { fname : x } }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest version uses [nested record updates](https://liamgoodacre.github.io/purescript/records/2017/01/29/nested-record-updates.html) and looks like this:

```
updateU :: XName -> String -> XName
updateU = _ { xname { fname = _ } }
```